# Read array user input using methods (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, input, methods

So I have to write some code that has a user input the highest temperatures for each day of the week and a method to find the hottest day (highest integer) out of the array the user has inputted. The problem is how do I write the method so that it can read the user inputs?

this is what the output should be:

```
Please enter the highest temperature of each day in a week (start with Sunday):
25
35
15 
34 
21 
25 
23  
The hottest temperature is 35
```

This is the code I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static int[] array;

    public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      int array[] = new int[7];
      System.out.println("Please enter the highest temperature of each day in a week (start with Sunday): ");
      for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){

          array[i] = scanner.nextInt();

          getHottest(array[i]);
          
      }
    }

        public static void getHottest(){

            int max;

            max = array[0];
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if(max < array[i])
                {
                    max = array[i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The hottest temperature is " + max + " degrees");
    
        }
     
  }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Your code seems to be doing what you intended

Comment: Why are you using two `int[]` arrays?

Answer (score 0):

No need for the below code as it is not necessary for your code to work.

```java
private static int[] array;
```

You need to invoke the `getHottest` after the `for` loop.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    array[i] = scanner.nextInt();    
}
getHottest(array);
```

Update the method signature of `getHottest` as

```java
public static void getHottest(int[] array)
```

Also the loop inside `getHottest` should iterate 7 times similar to the loop for user input.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has been said above, a few suggestions for good programming practices:
Be consistent in your array declarations (first form is more commonly used in Java programs).

```
int[] array;
int array[];
```

Use a [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) so you don't have to worry about closing a scanner once you're done using it.

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    ...
}
```

rather than

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
....
scanner.close(); // or forgetting it altogether!
```

You should be clear and explicit when asking for input (such as the temperature unit used, in this case Fahrenheit). It's also important to consider data validation wherever user input is required, although it's not really needed for a program like this (unless you really feel like checking for values below absolute zero?).
I also added the current day of the week to the start of each line for the user's convenience. It's not hard to implement and makes the program easier to use.

Your program doesn't actually need any array or the getHottest() method, although it's good that you created that method in the first place rather than dumping it into the main method. Since all that you really need from this array is the maximum value, what matters when a user enters a number is whether it's larger than your max variable, which makes the loop much simpler.

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    String[] daysOfWeek = new String[] {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    int maxTemperature = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    System.out.println("Please enter the highest temperature (°F) for each day of the week:");
    for (String dayOfWeek : daysOfWeek) {
        System.out.printf("%s: ", dayOfWeek);
        int inputTemperature = scanner.nextInt();
        if (inputTemperature > maxTemperature) {
            maxTemperature = inputTemperature;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("The highest temperature is %d °F.", maxTemperature);
}
```